# Only the old version of pgfplots is available with MiKTeX (version 1.7)

Tags: pgfplots, miktex, updating

I am looking for a solution to install the last version (currently 1.8) of `pgfplots` via the package manager MiKTeX on Windows. However, MiKTeX only offers the old version 1.7 of `pgfplots`.

Is there a way to force MiKTeX to install the new version?

Comment: if the new version is on CTAN, and miktex doesn't offer an update after a reasonable time you can make a feature request.

Comment: Just sent the feature request.

Comment: What do you get when you run the tex file `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfplots}\begin{document}\pgfplotsversion\end{document}` ?

Comment: Well, I get 1.8, then everything should be OK ! In the package manager, the version displayed is 1.7, which confused me.

Comment: Ah OK, the version info in MikTeX is wrong then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version info in MikTeX was wrong.

Running the TeX file: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgfplots}\begin{document}\pgfplotsversion\en‌​d{document}` the result shows the version number 1.8