# pgfplots: v1.12 installed, but appears to be v1.10

Tags: pgfplots

Under Windows (MikTex 2.9) I have the following problem: I want to use the great box plots provided by the pgfplot package in the current version 1.12.

The manual tells me to put

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
```

in the preamble of my document. That's what I did but running latex leads to the error

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.12' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'
```

The errror disappear when I put compat=1.10 as version number. So I truly updated all my packages via the MikTex Package Manager (Admin) and MikTex told me that I have the package pgfplots in version 1.12.1 installed.

Unfortunately, the error occured again, even if I uninstalled the pgfpackage using the package manager and relied on the setting "Install missing packages on-the-fly" in MikTex Options (Admin).

I took the following mini example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132053/only-the-old-version-of-pgfplots-is-available-with-miktex-version-1-7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsversion
\end{document}
```

and I obtain the output 1.10. It seems that I still have an old version of pgfplots installed.

So, I tried to do what the pgfmanual tells me (in chapter 2.5.3): I can force to use some package by setting a root link in the MikTex settings to a path where I have some packages. I downloaded the current version from [the developer site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/files/latest/download?source=files) and still get the error and output 1.10 from the mini example.

Could anybody please give me a hint what I can do to get the current version of pgfplots running? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Check in the log-file *where* pgfplots is installed -- probably in your user tree which means that you should update with the user update manager.

Comment: Thank you very much, @UlrikeFischer! That solved the problem. I used the Admin instance (hoping that it has all the rights it needs) - but the user-instance is the one that updates the packages that are used when I run LaTeX...

Comment: It depends. The user-instance will update the packages you installed as user.

Comment: Okay, I see. So, should one only use one of the two instances to avoid such problems? Are packages that are installed on-the-fly installed by the me or the Admin?

Comment: I don't know for sure. Imho the on-the-fly dialog lets you choose if the package is install for you or for all. But I have only one instance of all the tools as I installed miktex in single user mode in my user account to avoid all these problems ...

Comment: The only problem user mode is that I can never find the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @UlrikeFischer. She pointed me to this solution:

The version problem occured because the Admin instance of the MikTex package manager was used to update pgfplots.

The packages were installed in the user directory

```
USER\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgfplots
```

Therefore, one may not use the admin package manager but the non-admin one to update the packages that were installed by the current user (in my case they were installed by MiKTex on the fly).